# Sliding Panel visible programmatically in AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Tags: android, panel, visible, sliding

I need to hide the Sliding Layout of the [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/) library until one button is clicked: in this case, the panel get visibile and it can be expanded \ collapsed.
I tried in this way:

onCreate:

```
dragview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dragView);
dragview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and on click:

```
dragview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

But it seems not working, I can see only a full blank screen.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

solved with:

```
dragview.hidePanel();
```

and

```
dragview.hidePanel();
```

Those two methods were supported by the library

Comment: No I don't find any function here

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!,

to hide it,

```
slidingPanelLayout.setPanelHeight(0);
```

to show it,

```
slidingPanelLayout.setPanelHeight(//YOUR DIMENS VALUE);
```